# Generating a heatmap from a hdf file

Tags: pandas, numpy, seaborn, heatmap, hdf5

I want to generate a heatmap out of a hdf5 File, where intensity is an 2d matrix and x_range and z_range are the ranges for the axis.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib as plt

#Data Aquisition
file = h5py.File('scan.h5', 'r')

intensity = file.get('intensity')
intensity = np.array(intensity)

x_range = file.get('x range')
x_range = np.array(x_range)

z_range = file.get('z range')
z_range = np.array(z_range)
```

Now i have tried to create a pivot table using pandas via:

```
#Pivot Table
df = pd.DataFrame({'intensity': intensity, 'x_range': x_range, 'z_range': z_range})
result= df.pivot(index= 'z_range', columns= 'x_range', values= 'intensity')
```

Here the problem occurs that intensity must be 1D and intensity is a matrix.
The plotting is done by:

```
#Ploting
heat_map = sb.heatmap(result, cmap="Spectral_r", cbar_kws={'label': 'Countrate [arb. units]'})
plt.xlabel("x direction [µm]")
plt.ylabel("z direction [µm]")
plt.show()
```

Additionally to that I want to have the origin at the bottom left corner at the heatmap.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to plot it just by using the dataframe like so:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: And via 
```heat_map = sb.heatmap(intensity, yticklabels= z_range, xticklabels= x_range , cmap="Spectral_r", cbar_kws={'label': 'Countrate [arb. units]'})
```
one can add the range of the axis to use the data from the hdf5 file.